# How to create a privately shared component library which can be used across multiple react projects

Tags: reactjs, npm

**Following Scenario**

- Project 1 needs to use `CustomButton.jsx`
- Project 2 needs to use `CustomButton.jsx`

**Current Solution**

Copy paste `CustomButton.jsx` into both Project 1 & 2.

**Desired Solution**

1. Create Project 3 which includes `CustomButton.jsx`
2. Store Project 3 in a shared environment (like a public company directory e.g. `D://dev/react/my-component-library`)
3. Install Project 3 via npm for Project 1 & 2 and add dependency to `package.json` to keep consistency accross git clones.
4. Import `CustomButton.jsx` with import statement in Project 1 & 2: `import { CustomButton } from "my-component-library"`

**Questions**

1. What kind of Project is Project 3? Is it build with `create-react-app` or which other tool can be used?
2. How can I create a local/private npm package out of Project 3?
3. How can I utilize a shared, local environment for that private package.
4. How can I use the package in Project 1 & 2?

The components are fairly simple and don't contain complex logic.

**EDIT**

This shouldn't cost me anything (private npm does) or use 3rd party hosting, since I already have a privately shared environment/server/directory and I can host/store the packages there.

Comment: you can make git submodule
and share your code every project

Comment: Never heard of git submodules, seems interesting and may fit my needs. Still a lot of questions are unanswered.

Comment: You can also try ` GitHub Package Registry` if you shared stuff is < 500mb, but I have only heard of it, haven't used before

Comment: git submodules, it a child git project which one link with parend project

Comment: check link here https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved this problem in vue. But the steps should be pretty similar in react.

**1.** Create a project with your components (`create-react-app` should be fine. You will export your components only anyway, that's why the project setup is irrelevant. It is just useful for development and to test your components.)

**2.** Use [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) to bundle your react components (there are many tutorials online, just google "rollup react component library")

**3.** Add a new script to your `package.json` to bundle your app using `rollup -c`.
Then use [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-pack) to create the package.

```
"build:lib": "rollup -c && npm pack"
```

This will create a zipped package with only the files you need with following pattern:

`[package-name]-[package-version].tgz` e.g. `my-react-components-0.1.0.tgz`

You can influence the resulting package of `npm pack` by modifying attributes in your `package.json`, e.g. `"version"`, `"name"`, `"main"`, `"files"` will influence the output.

**4.** Now you can install your packages locally from another project:

```
npm i ../path/to/library/my-react-components-0.1.0.tgz
```

This will add a new dependency to your `package.json`:

```
"my-react-components": "file: ../path/to/library/my-react-components-0.1.0.tgz"
```

**5.** Based on your rollup setup you can then use your library like any other library:

```
import { MyComponent } from "my-react-components";
```

You might also have to import the styles:

```
import "my-react-components/index.css"
```

If you need a more detailed explanation on a step, just comment below and I will add further information.

Comment: Can i  create a lib  which accepts the parameter  ? i might need detailed explanation can u help me out  ? @oemera

Comment: What kind of parameter?

Comment: say i want to send json list into the package from external application

Comment: By the way. You can use nuxt 3 layers on a vue project. Your "core" layer components (project 3) will be accessible in layers (project 1 & 2) extended from "core" layer.

See https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/layers

Comment: Funny enough, I am actually using nuxt layers now too now. :)

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Project 3 is just like any npm packages (e.g. ui library) you install, you can build with `create-react-app`, or not to if you want. Simply export everything you want to share from that library and import them from your main project like when you use any library. You may publish it to npm like [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-a-beautiful-tiny-npm-package-and-publish-it-2881d4307f78/), or use private repo like [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-repository)

**2.** For npm, you may check the tutorial I mentioned above. For Nexus, google and you may come up with something like [this](https://blog.sonatype.com/publishing-private-npm-packages-to-nexus)

**3 & 4.** After publishing your package, you can do `npm install your-package` in any of your project.

Comment: I edited my post with some restriction. Unfortunately neither npm nor Nexus is a great solution for my use case. But thanks for answering my 1. question.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options for that. You can do it by creating an org on npm ([details here](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages)). Also, you can use bits n pieces ([details here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/introducing-bit-organizations-3254f1b9d738)). You even can prefer something more simple like yarn workspaces ([details here](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/)).

Comment: I edited my post, and sadly those solutions doesn't fit to my requirements. Also I don't use yarn.

Comment: So Lerna wouldn't work for you too... right? https://lerna.js.org/